# Magento 2: registry() content missing while page refreshing

Tags: magento2, theme, registry

When loading a product detail page,

at first

```
$this->_registry->registry()
```

gets an output content.

But, while refreshing the same page,

```
$this->_registry->registry()
```

content missing.

This code was written on a theme custom module.

Comment: Where you put this code line? Block, controller, template?

Comment: file path- /Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php. Its a custom module on the theme folder

Comment: Can you add more details with the code lines?

Comment: We definitely need more info, that's like asking "My car won't start, it's got a customised engine, how do I fix it?".

Comment: @BenCrook sorry for the poor information. The custom module is using   $this->_registry->register() to store the stock status of product,i.e, whether it is in in stock or not. While loading the page for the first time stock status of the product is renderde corectly but on page refresh this data is not displaying correctly.This is the code _$this->_registry->unregister('notif_data'); $this->_registry->register('notif_data', $aStockStatus);_ I tried this after disabling cache and it was working fine.Any idea how to solve this problem..?

Comment: @RitaJose I don't know enough about that to give any help sorry :(